# What is the best way modeling in Scala with Spring Data JPA

Tags: scala, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Scala does not get first class support as Kotlin in Spring.

I tried to create a Spring Boot API application with Scala.

- Spring Boot 2.2.0.M5
- Spring Data JPA
- H2
- Scala 2.13

I created a JPA Entity with case class like:

```scala
@Entity
case class Post(@BeanProperty title: String, @BeanProperty content: String) {
  def this() {
    this(null, null)
  }

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @BeanProperty
  var id: Long = _

  @BeanProperty
  val createdOn: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()

  override def toString: String = s"Post[id:$id, title:$title, content:$content, createdOn:$createdOn]"
}
```

And create a Repository using trait, it works.

```scala
trait PostRepository extends JpaRepository[Post, Long]
```

I want to try bean validation.

```scala
class PostForm {

  @NotNull
  @NotEmpty
  @BeanProperty var title: String = _
  @BeanProperty var content: String = _
}
```

And in the controller, create a POST method like:

```scala
  @PostMapping
  def save(@RequestBody @Valid form: PostForm, errors: BindingResult) = errors.hasErrors match {
    case true => {
      badRequest().build()
    }
    case _ => {
      val data = Post(title = form.title, content = form.content)
      val saved = posts.save(data)
      created(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(saved.id).toUri).build()
    }
  }
```

It works.

But the model classes are little tedious. I am trying to use a case class like the following:

```scala
case class PostForm(@NotNull @NotEmpty @BeanProperty title: String, @BeanProperty content: String)
```

<del>The validation does not work.</del>

1. When we are modeling for JPA etc, case class or generic class is better?
2. <del>Why we can not apply the Bean Validation annotations as Kotlin data clase in the case class?</del>

**Update**: Got this work like:

```scala
case class PostForm(@(NotNull@field) @(NotEmpty@field) @BeanProperty title: String, @BeanProperty content: String)
```

The source codes is hosted on my [Github](https://github.com/hantsy/scala-sandbox/tree/master/spring-boot-demo).

Answer (score 1):

Case class fields are considered as `val`s by default, which means you can't set a new value to them. `@BeanProperty`, however, is to automatically generate field **setters** and getters.

You may try adding `var` keywords to the fields explicitly.

```
case class PostForm(
  @NotNull @NotEmpty @BeanProperty var title: String,
  @BeanProperty var content: String
)
```